# Admin certification (ADM 201)

Tags: certification, certificates, summer19, spring19, adm201

I have registered for ADM 201 admin certification for Spring 19, and my exam is on August 20. But Salesforce is coming out with new release on August 14 (Summer 19). So will questions the be about Summer 19 or Spring 19?

Comment: What would be your actual question?

Comment: I have registered for Salesforce certified admin (sp19)exam which I scheduled on aug 20 but as Salesforce is coming with new summer release on aug 14 so the questions which will come is that of sp19 or summer 19.

Answer (score 1):

The premise of your question is incorrect. The current release of Salesforce is Summer '19. The release that is currently approaching public preview is Winter '20, which will be released in early October.

The certification exams do not include questions about releases that are not yet public.